# How to export GUI items from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, prefab

I purchased a UI asset from the [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) Asset Store, which includes buttons and icons organized as prefabs. I would like to extract these elements as images to edit them in [Photoshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop). How can I accomplish this?

I want to open this asset in Photoshop to edit buttons and icons.

Comment: normally there wil be a folder of images you can edit in the asset folder

Answer (score 0):

The images will be stored somewhere in the project.

Here's how you can find them

- The prefabs (or a child in the prefab) will have Image components.
- These image components have a `Source Image` attribute which points to the image to show.
- Clicking on the value of this attribute will reveal the source image location in the project view.
- Then right clicking and selecting `reveal in explorer` or `show in finder` will bring it up in whatever file viewer you have.